# Vuejs and Laravel Post Request CORS

Tags: laravel, cors, vue.js, vue-resource

I dont get it. I am struggling with this since hours

I am using Vue.js with Laravel and try to make a POST Request to an external API.

But i am always getting a CORS error on my Vue POST Request

```
methods: {
            chargeCustomer(){
                this.$http.post('/api/chargeCustomer', this.payment).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                },function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                });
            }
        }
```

**ERROR**

> MLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.mollie.com/payscreen/select-method/JucpqJQses. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://payment.dev' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I installed the [Laravel CORS Package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) for my Backend and added the middleware to my route e.g

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    Route::post('/api/chargeCustomer', 'Backend\PaymentController@chargeCustomer');
});
```

But i am still getting the error. I also tried to add the Vue Headers with

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*';
```

With the same result/error.

Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up the CORS headers from the middleware. Maybe you need some extra setup?

Anyway, you can create your own middleware and set up the CORS headers in the `handle()` method like the following example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{
    return $next($request)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://yourfrontenddomain.com') // maybe put this into the .env file so you can change the URL in production.
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*') // or specify `'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'` etc as the second parameter if you want to restrict the methods that are allowed.
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization') // or add your headers.
}
```

Add your custom middleware to the global `$middleware` array (under `CheckForMaintenanceMode::class`) in the Kernel.php class and you should be good to go.

Comment: And if that won't help, like it didn't work for me for Laravel 5.5+, also check your `config/cors.php` you may need to set allowed origins, headers, and methods there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Other way (without creating a new laravel middleware) is add these headers at the begining of your routes.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

and add this before your interceptors on vue:
`Vue.http.options.crossOrigin = true`