# CORS Laravel VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, axios

I'm trying to do a get with axios from VueJS to Laravel which is my API.

I got this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.test/api/events/1/' from origin >'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control->Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>   at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)

I've tried to create a middleware named 'cors' like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860851/vuejs-and-laravel-post-request-cors) but it's not working for me or maybe I'm doing it badly ?

Strange thing ? is that's working with Postman.

Thank for the help ! :)

Comment: Did you try the second answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199615/1308765

Comment: I don't have any file named routes.php but I've tried on api\vendor\symfony\routing\Route.php and on \api\routes\api.php, am I doing it wrongly ?

Comment: @J.Doe Never edit anything in `vendor`. `api/routes/api.php` is the file to edit - Laravel used to have all routes in `routes.php`, but it's not split up into web and API versions.

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 5):

> Servers are used to host web pages, applications, images, fonts, and
>   much more. When you use a web browser, you are likely attempting to
>   access a distinct website (hosted on a server). Websites often request
>   these hosted resources from different locations (servers) on the
>   Internet. Security policies on servers mitigate the risks associated
>   with requesting assets hosted on different server. Let's take a look
>   at an example of a security policy: same-origin.
>
> The same-origin policy is very restrictive. Under this policy, a
>   document (i.e., like a web page) hosted on server A can only interact
>   with other documents that are also on server A. In short, the
>   same-origin policy enforces that documents that interact with each
>   other have the same origin.

---

Check this [CORS](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) library made for Laravel usage. 
Installation is easy:

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

The defaults are set in `config/cors.php`

```
return [
     /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

`allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders` and `allowedMethods` can be set to `array('*')` to accept any value.

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

If you want to allow CORS on a specific middleware group or route, add the HandleCors middleware to your group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       // ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        // ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors

Comment: Hi,

I've tried it but it's still not working...
I'm using Laragon as local server (so it's Apache server) if it can help to find the answer

Comment: Hi J.Doe, i found this post...how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Tried sending Axios request from Vue app to Laravel backend.

I had CORS Error and I couldn't find the solution.

After following request execution in `vendor` files I found out that I was simply testing it wrong.

I was testing on url: `http://localhost/api`, but in `config/cors.php` there is:

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
```

So all I had to do was to change request to `http://localhost/api/...` and it started working.
Another solution is adding `'api'` to `paths` array in **config/cors.php** if you want to use `http://localhost/api`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is with the same origin policy. you can read about it on the Mozilla site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control).
it is basally to proven un authorized access to web servers. you can change the way your web server reacts and i also in that link i have included.